# Start up cmder ConEmu console in a specific folder

Tags: windows, cmd, conemu, cmder

I want start my Cmder console in this route **C:\xampp\htdocs**, but I don't understand the syntax of 'Task parameters'. For example:

```
 `/icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe`"
```

Can anyone translate for this? `C:\xampp\htdocs to -> /icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe`"

So I could edit the **config** and place my custom folder:
[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change `%USERPROFILE%` to desired folder instead.

Comment: Exactly as I've said. Replace `%USERPROFILE%` with `C:\xampp\htdocs`

Comment: In fact, syntax with examples is described thoroughly in docs: http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html

Answer (score 51):

Go to Setup and Click on 'Startup dir...' button and specify startup directory.
As you can see in example bellow startup directory is C:\DEV
[image]

Comment: As of version 171025, this is the solution, not to mention that it is a lot cleaner than the others suggested.

Comment: It should be noted that this solution has side effect that "cmder here" contextual menu does not work anymore. It will always open the startup directory you have set  up. See [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1735) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

### Two ways:

1. If you want to change the location PER task: do what "Maximus" said, change %USERPROFILE% to the specific location. The downside is that when creating a new console window, the "startup directory for new process" (see image below) will still be the default ConEmu installation directory.
2. If you want to change the "Startup directory for new process:" location (from the default ConEmu installation directory to custom) when creating a new console:

[image]

**Then create a shortcut for ConEmu / Cmder and change the "Start in:" attribute in the shortcut properties; like so:**

[image]

Now simply use the shortcut instead of the exe. This has the benefit of changing the start location for ALL the tasks (all terminals you have setup).

Answer (score 5):

Instructions: Open Cmder -> Settings -> Tasks -> select {cmd::Cmder} (in my case). On the bottom (below textarea) you have button named "Startup dir...", and than select startup directory. Close cmder, and start again. That's it, enjoy

Answer (score 4):

you can do it like this:

1. edit `<APP_DIR>/config/user-startup.cmd` file,append a line(suppose dir is 'e:'):

   `@cd /d "e:"`
2. restart cmder.

ref:

[cmder config](http://note.isongli.cn/blog/post/admin/cmder%E9%85%8D%E7%BD%AE.md)

Answer (score 4):

For last version, you can do this:

1. **Open Cmder**
2. Presh: **Windows + ALT + T**
   [image]
3. Push "**Startup dir...**" button
4. **Select Folder**
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

In the `cmder/vendor/init.bat`

**Find this line**

`:: Set home path`

**And before it add**

`@cd  /d "C:/YOUR_DIR_NAME/"`

---

[REF](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/91)

Comment: Vendor directory is not supposed to be edited by the end user and will be overwritten when user unpacks a new version of cmder. Use the config directory instead. See https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#upgrading point 2 last bullet. "Editing files under [cmder_root]/vendor is not recommended since you will need to re-apply these changes after any upgrade. All user customizations should go in [cmder_root]/config folder."

Answer (score 1):

I added the line as in the screenshot. It is working for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file: \CMDER_DIRECTORY\config\user-profile.cmd

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs
```

On bellow example, I've changed the directory and created a rotine to start homestead.

```
:: use this file to run your own startup commands
:: use  in front of the command to prevent printing the command

:: uncomment this to have the ssh agent load when cmder starts
:: call "%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%/cmd/start-ssh-agent.cmd"

:: uncomment this next two lines to use pageant as the ssh authentication agent
:: SET SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/.ssh-pageant-auth-sock
:: call "%GIT_INSTALL_ROOT%/cmd/start-ssh-pageant.cmd"

:: you can add your plugins to the cmder path like so
:: set "PATH=%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\whatever;%PATH%"

e:
cd ../../../../../Homestead

@echo off

:Ask
echo Would you like to start the Homestead?(Y/N)

set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Yes(y) ou No(n): %=%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="Y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no

cls
echo Invalid option
echo - 
echo -
goto Ask

:yes
vagrant up
goto finalMessage

:no 
cls
goto finalMessage

:finalMessage
echo Your console is ready Mr. Chapela.
```